# SQL password - local database at work, how to secure it?

Tags: sql-server, database, passwords, local

I have started a new job and there is currently no database to store data which I need to perform some financial analysis (what a shame). I have to start from scratch and build a few tables which I will load every day. This is all new to me.

I will ask IT to install SQL Server Management Studio as well as a local server instance, in which I will store my tables (similar to SQLExpress instance installed on my personal laptop).

I will then load the data everyday, I am worried that other people on the network can play around and amend the data.

Do I need to secure the database or not (since its a local install)?

In case they install it on a common drive, how do I make sure that a password is needed to get in or that other people only have read access?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Database access must be explicitly granted.  If the database files are on a common drive, make sure it is in an appropriately secured directory.

Comment: You'll likely find a better audience for questions like this over at out dba.stackexchange.com sister site.

Comment: In addition to what Dan said, you can also specify a local user for the database itself. Or on the server. You can lock it down pretty tight if you don't want anyone else to mess with or look at your tables.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. "lock down pretty tight" sounds good to me, do you know how to this or can you point at any resource for me to explore and learn? Thanks and Regards.